# How to invert react native vector icon buttons color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, vector-icons

I am using [Vector Icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) as [Icon.Button](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#iconbutton-component) and I would like to have two Cancel and Accept Icons.

I am doing this:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{borderColor: 'red'}}> 
        <Icon.Button backgroundColor={RED} name="ios-close-circle-outline" size={20} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={{borderColor: 'red'}}>
        <Icon.Button backgroundColor={GREEN} name="ios-checkmark-circle-outline" size={20} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

**I am getting this:**

[image]

**I would like this:**

[image]

**How to invert react native vector icon buttons color?  Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `backgroundColor` to transparent, set the color property to the preferred color and bump the size.

Answer (score -3):

If anybody is here because they would like to know how to invert colors using css, then you may simply use `filter: invert(1);`

Comment: Question is specifically about react native and I think CSS does not apply here.